# Messing up of non-typical characters in DOS

Tags: batch-file, dos

A command-line program outputs a list of file paths. I pipe the output to another program to do further processing. It all works fine until a file path is encountered that contains a "strange" character (ó, î, ä, etc.).

The cause of the problem seems to be the behavior described next:

#### Test 1

When I execute this command in cmd.exe,

```
C:\temp> echo ó > o.txt
```

the contents of the created file will be the character ¢.

#### Test 2

I created an input file, o_src.txt, (with my text editor) that contains the character ó.

The command

```
C:\temp> type o_src.txt
```

will print this character in cmd.exe
¾

If I execute

```
C:\temp>type o.txt
```

(o.txt from TEST 1) the result is ó

#### Test 3

After execution of the command

```
C:\temp> type o_src.txt > o_dst.txt
```

then the contents of o_src.txt and o_dst.txt are the same.

How does this work?

ASCII code of ó: F3 / 243 
ASCII code of ¢: A2 / 162 
ASCII code of ¾: BE / 190

Comment: In the most situations it is a good choice to change the code page to 1252.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to change the code page using `CHCP`. Look at these questions for more info.

[Batch script is not executed if chcp was called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182568/batch-script-is-not-executed-if-chcp-was-called)

[What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: Thanks. I added chcp 1252 at the top of the batch file and now it works.