# chcp 65001 and a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-vista

I have a problem with `chcp 65001` command in Windows shell.

I need to generate a list of files in a folder.
So I ran cmd.exe, typed

```
cd folder
dir /B /O:N > list_of_files.txt
```

It worked, but I had a problem with special, non-ASCII characters which are in some file names.
So I added
`chcp 65001`

Everything worked, but when I put these commands into a .bat file, the script doesn't work.

So

```
cd folder
chcp 65001
dir /B /O:N > list_of_files.txt
```

doesn't generate the list.

and

```
cd folder
chcp 65001 && dir /B /O:N > list_of_files.txt
```

as well as

```
cd folder
chcp 65001 > nul && dir /B /O:N > list_of_files.txt
```

generates the list, but with the default encoding :/.

Everything works in cmd.exe, but not in .bat files.

I've read the topic: [stackoverflow.com/questions/2182568/batch-script-is-not-executed-if-chcp-was-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182568/batch-script-is-not-executed-if-chcp-was-called), but it didn't help.

EDIT:
I partially solved my problem, changing `chcp 65001` to `chcp 1250` because all characters were in this encoding. But actually this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What happens when you put these four commands into a batch file and run it? `cd folder` `chcp 65001` `dir /B /O:N` `pause`

Comment: foxdrive: the cmd window opens for a short while and immediately closes

Comment: did you try it with the `pause` command on line 4?

Comment: Yes. It didn't pause. I also tried `timeout 5`. But when I change 65001 to other valid encoding, everything works.

Comment: If you paste this into a cmd window - what do you see? `chcp 65001 & dir /B /O:N & pause`

Comment: I see that enconding was changed, a list of files and Press any key to continue. But if I add `> list.txt` it does generates the list but without unicode characters (as I wrote in the question in the example).

Comment: You said `the script doesn't work` and `doesn't generate the list.` and it wasn't clear what you were doing or what the result was from the script.  Because the pause didn't work it looked like your batch file name was causing a problem.

Comment: Related.
• [What encoding to get Å Ä Ö to work](https://superuser.com/q/675369)
• [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654)
• [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490)
• [chcp 65001 and a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32182619)
• [Making Swedish characters show properly in Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660264)

Answer (score 8):

"chcp 65001" does not work before Windows 7.  It will cause the batch to terminate immediately.  There is no work-around.

I have verified this by directly testing 2003, XP, Vista, 2008, 7, 8, and 10.

Comment: There is exist a binary patch for `Windows XP`: http://consolesoft.com/p/cmd-xp-65001-fix/ But seems it is only for `Windows XP 32-bit`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `cmd /U`. See http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html:

> Most common text files are ANSI, use these switches when you need to
>   convert the character set. These options will affect [piping or
>   redirecting](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to a file:
>
> - `/A`     Output ANSI characters
> - `/U`     Output UNICODE characters (UCS-2 Little Endian)

Here's my attempt (launch it under `cmd /A`, of course):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

:: create a UNICODE file with Byte Order Mark using `wmic` 
chcp 852 >NUL
>list_of_files.txt wmic os get localdatetime

:: store a line with BOM to a variable
:: although FINDSTR does not support UTF-16 files
:: it will read first three bytes at least
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('
    findstr "^" list_of_files.txt
  ') do set "UTF8BOM=%%G"

:: write BOM only* to a file (* echo writes hexadecimal value FFFE0D0A)
:: the `<NUL set /p =text` trick does not work: chokes down leading `FF`  
>list_of_files.txt echo(%UTF8BOM:~0,2%

chcp 65001 >NUL
:: add CRLF in  Unicode (hexadecimal 0D000A00)
>>list_of_files.txt cmd /U /C echo(

:: add result of `dir /B /O:N` in Unicode 
>>list_of_files.txt cmd /U /C dir /B /O:N

:: check the result: still invalid first line, see output
type list_of_files.txt
chcp 852 >NUL
```

**Output**. Still invalid first line (that hexadecimal `0D0A`), sorry; use another method to get *pure* Utf-8 byte order mark:

```
==>cmd /A /C D:\bat\SO\UTF8BOM32182619.bat
਍
cpANSI_OoCcSsUu.txt
cpANSI_ÖöÇçŞşÜü.txt
escrzyaie.txt
ěščřžýáíé.txt
list_of_files.txt

==>
```

Comment: But the user doesn't use cmd.exe, he just run the .bat file, so how can I use `/U` in a .bat file?

Comment: Why don't you _read_ the batch script provided? There is `cmd /U` used _twice_...  And what do you mean by _he just **run** the .bat file_? Double-click it? Just take a look in Task Manager: _any_ .bat script is always performed in a `cmd` instance...

Comment: If you want a BOM in the beginning of a file, just make template files like `efbbbf.bin` or `feff.bin` with respective characters in a notepad like `notepad++` and just redirect it into your file: `type efbbbf.bin > "file_with_bom.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, make sure that **file format** of the actual file is same as **codepage** of the console (cmd.exe). Swedish characters åäö are used commonly.

In editor (in this case) Notepad++ hit "Encode>Convert to ANSI"

In script (batchfile) run same codepage as the file (Microsoft's 1252 ANSI version),
File:

```
chcp 1252
cd c:\My Folder\Filename_with_åäö-characters.txt
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 2003 worked this:

```
chcp 65001 && cmd /C dir C:\WINDOWS\* && chcp 866
```

`C:\windows\*` - only sample

`&& chcp 866` - default code page and this allow to continue batch

Answer (score 0):

> Tested on Windows 7 only, may not work on Windows Vista.

Apparently `chcp` doesn't affect `dir` directly.

Parse the output of `dir` and print it via `echo`:

```
chcp 65001
>list_of_files.txt (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /O:N') do echo %%a)
```

Note: the output file won't have UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Please elaborate. It works on Win7SP1x64 English here.

Comment: Did you put this into a .bat file? I have Windows Vista 32bit.

Comment: Yes, it's in the batch file, otherwise `%%` wouldn't work. Blaming Vista is the obvious choice, it's notorious for hard-to-discover bugs and underdeveloped features.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a problem [I recently met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999060/show-characters-with-accents-in-redirect-file-output-txt)

```
cd folder
dir /B /O:N > list_of_files.tmp
cmd /U /C type list_of_files.tmp>list_of_files.txt
del list_of_files.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the defaults for cmd?
You can control the code page simply by creating a file %HOMEPATH%\init.cmd.
This sets defaults for cmd.exe.
Mine says:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 65001 > nul
```