# error MSB1009: Project file does not exist if file name and folder written in Japanese Language

Tags: .net, batch-file, unicode

Hello I am getting an error the Project file Not getting If Project File written in Japanese. Like Here is my File Path "C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2\HAL9\v3_07\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷.csproj"  In this location, csproj file exists. I run a batch file to build this csproj  a C# project but I got this error "error MSB1009: Project file does not exist"......

And in the console, I got that  C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2\HAL9\v3_07\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ.csproj  Here you can see in the batch file what I wrote the file path changed The text has been changed. Here is my batch file code

```
  set rootPath=C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2
  set basePath3=%rootPath%\HAL9
  set filename=%rootPath%\buildLog\%yyyy%%mm%%dd%%hh%%mm%%ss%.log
  set csproj指示せん印刷=%basePath3%\v3_07\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷.csproj
  set msbuild_new="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
  Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

  mkdir %rootPath%\buildLog
  @echo %csproj指示せん印刷%
  C:
  cd C:\
  cd %basePath3%
  tf get
  if errorlevel 1 goto ON_EXIT

 dotnet build %csproj指示せん印刷% /t:%buildCmd% /p:Configuration=Release /fl 
  /flp:logfile=%filename%;verbosity=diagnostic
 if errorlevel 1 goto ON_EXIT
```

I used this batch file code to run this and the main problem is in the varible and line of Batch file "set csproj指示せん印刷=%basePath3%\v3_07\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷\指示せん印刷.csproj" in the  file it changes in runtime as I console it "C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2\HAL9\v3_07\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ\謖・､ｺ縺帙ｓ蜊ｰ蛻ｷ.csproj" 2 are different . What operation and settings I have to change. I think it is a unicode related problem . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, the project is C# based project and as you can see set msbuild_new="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
  Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

Comment: okay I remove C# tag

Comment: You can use the `CHCP` command to change the Active Code Page at the top of your script.

Comment: @Squashman can you show and write where and how and what should I write I am not so good in batch file . Your help is highly appreciatable . Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you perhaps look at the help file for the command?  I don't know what code page you need to use.  You have to figure that out on your own.  Here is a list of [Code Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) you can use.

Comment: about the CHCP I heard it the first from you . Yes I have searched and found  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182619/chcp-65001-and-a-bat-file)   if you help me in the top what i will write in my bat file .

Comment: There are 22 usage example of `CHCP` in that link.  What is stopping you from putting `CHCP #####` at the top of your script?  Where `#####` equals the code page number you need to use.

Comment: yes I m asking you the format like 
I write @echo off
:ON_INPUT
cls
chcp 10001
set buildCmd=rebuild

Is it Okay

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid the use of non-ansi characters in variablenames (eg `csproj指示せん印刷` ) - just call it `csproj` , use the `set` syntax `set "var=value"`, avoid assigning `"` as part of the value and insert `"` as required (`"%msbuild_new%"` with no `"` in the value instead of `%msbuild_new%`). I'd then try `for %%v in (%csproj%) do set "shortname=%%~sdpnxv"` and use `%shortname% ` in place of `%csproj%` for the remainder of the batch.

Comment: you mean this  set msbuild_new=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe  to set %msbuild_new%=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe   but the last point I dont understand

Comment: In the future, post an [mcve].  You probably want `dotnet build` to be `dotnet msbuild`. Also, [edit] your post to include the full build error.  If you have a solution file, specify that on your build command line.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8